# Semantic UI React - populate dropdown with remote content

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to implement a searchable dropdown (using Semantic UI React library) that is populated by matching results from the server. The user is presented with with an input box. As soon as they start typing a few characters, a request is made to a backend restful endpoint which returns matching search results. These results are displayed as values in the dropdown.

This was quite easy with plain Semantic UI (explained at https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#match-search-query-on-server).

But how can I achieve this with the React version of the library?

I can't figure out from the documentation (https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#usage-remote).

Can someone provide me with an example?

Answer (score 6):

I was able to code it as follows:

```
class MyDd extends React.Component {
  state = {options: []}

  onSearchChange = (e, value) => {
    axios.get(`/api/match?query=${value.searchQuery}`)
     .then((response) => {
       this.setState({options: response.data})
    })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Dropdown
        onSearchChange={this.onSearchChange}
        search
        selection
        options={this.state.options}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I also needed to set `search` in the Dropdown to identity (`options => options`) as it otherwise tried to filter my options based on their `text` property.